# Why am I getting a service dependency error when I haven't touched my .yml at all?

Tags: docker, debugging, docker-compose, dockerfile

Whenever I run `docker-compose up -d --build` to start working on my project, it started up my environment just fine up until yesterday.

Upon running `docker-compose up -d --build`, I get this annoying error that says: `ERROR: Service 'app' depends on service 'db' which is undefined.`

I'm not sure how this is happening out of no where as I've made absolutely no changes whatsoever to the `docker-compose.yml` file.  I've tried troubleshooting this extensively but to no avail.

What's wrong with my file?

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    app:
        build:
            args:
                user: sammy
                uid: 1000
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        working_dir: /var/www/
        environment:
            - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        networks:
            - lahmi

    myApp:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./docker-compose/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
            - ./docker-compose/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        ports:
            - 3307:3306
        networks:
            - lahmi

    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
            - 8005:80
        depends_on:
            - db
            - app
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks:
            - lahmi

networks:
    lahmi:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no service named `db` in `docker-compose.yml`. Changing `db` to `myApp` (database service) may work.

If you are referencing the database as `db` in service `app`, you must use links configuration to change `myApp` to `db` or change service name `myApp` to `db`.

> https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#links

Comment: thanks.  had to change `db` to `myApp` in both occurrences.